# googe-apps-script GoogleSheets dropdown with display name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dropdown menue in google sheets that references values from a different sheet.

Reference Sheet
A row Value1, Value 2
B row Value1:Value1_Description Value2:Value2_Description.

In my worksheet I have a dropdown menu in the cells that sets and displays Value1, Value2 etc. .

I would like the dropdown menu to display the display names from the reference sheet Value1:Value1_Description, Value2:Value2_Description etc. but only set Value1 Value2 etc. as a Value in the cell.

Exactly this but in Google Sheets https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4130-excel-drop-down-list-show-different-value.html

Or alternatively is it possible to have a dropdown menue where the values are modified once selected, for example having everything after : removed?

Comment: The linked post uses VBA. You could try to do the same but using Google Apps Script.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. You can use VBA on Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a hidden cell next to it which Vlookups the Value1 from the Value1_Description (assuming you keep them in two columns next to each other on the reference sheet)

Comment: Thanks. I just built and html dropdown that fires when a precursor selector is set.